# How to send image in servlet response to ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I am uploading an image file from database to jsp. I've selected image using SQL as below

```
select (logo_img_one) from accounts_logo where logo_usrm_id=1
```

I read the image using binarystream as

```
InputStream readImg = rs1.getBinaryStream(1);
```

and made content type as "image/jpeg" as

```
response.setContentType("image/jpg");
```

Now I want to know how to use getoutputstream of response to send the image to ajax and how to get in ajax. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work. JavaScript can't save the retrieved bytes locally or something and tell the browser to display it. Best what you can do is to pass an URL to the image back as a string and let JavaScript set it as the `src` attribute of a HTML `<img>` element.

E.g. in servlet

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().write(imageUrl); // e.g. "images/some.png"
```

and in JS

```
var imageUrl = xhr.responseText;
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = imageUrl;
document.getElementById("someDivId").appendChild(img);
```

This way a

```
<div id="someDivId"></div>
```

will dynamically end up in something like

```
<div id="someDivId><img src="images/some.png" /></div>
```

You can create an image servlet which streams the image from the DB to the outputstream of the response and map the servlet on `/images/*`. You can find an example [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can use output stream  as follows after setting contentType

```
   Printwritter out =response.getWritter();
   out.println(imageObject);
   out.flush
```

Comment: Images are binary data, not character data. Treating binary data like character data would only corrupt binary data.

Comment: set your content type as response.setContentType("image/gif");

Comment: Mr.BalusC stop criticizing other nd just focused in ur business. Because in my answer, I hv no where mention its character object.

Comment: Yes, you did. You suggested to use `Writer`.

Answer (score 0):

It might work... The idea is to set the src attribute of the image to something like:

```
src="data:image/png;base64,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"
```

the base64 string can be queried via ajax by calling your servlet and encode the input stream retrieved from DB.